# qBCCGo function in GAMLSS package (quantile function)

Tags: quantiles, gamlss

*I am working with GAMLSS technique and I use LMS (with three parameters of mean,variation and skewness) method. I found the follwoing formula to calculate the lower limit of normal as the link function for mu is log fucntion.*

```
LLN= exp(log(mu)+log(1-1.645*nu*sigma)/nu)
```

*In GAMLSS package, there is a function* `qBCCGo(p, mu = 1, sigma = 0.1, nu = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)` *to calculate the lower limit of normal for Box-Cox Cole and Green distribution (p should be 0.05)*

*LLN= 5th percentile of that particular distribution*

*But the results of these two functions are not the same.* *I would be so thankful if you provide me some advice.*

*Forexample:*

```
mu=0.8
nu=1.1
sigma=0.4
```

or

```
nu=1.2088855
 sigma=0.7251396
 mu=0.5203920
```

***(for the second example the function in R gives us the answer but the formula would give us NA)***

```
qBCCGo(0.05, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, nu = nu, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
exp(log(mu)+log(1-1.645*nu*sigma)/nu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qBCCGo is exact, so use that.

[Note the formula for LLN is approximate and

log(1-1.645 * nu * sigma) will be NA, if 1 < 1.645 * nu * sigma.]

Yes,

for calculating the ULN we need to use

qBCCGo(0.05, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, nu = nu, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = FALSE)

or

qBCCGo(0.95, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, nu = nu, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)

which are exact and so should be used.

[The approximate formula is exp(log(mu)+log(1+1.645*nu*sigma)/nu).]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Robert, thanks so much, Just for double checking : for calculating the ULN we need to use qBCCGo(0.05, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, nu = nu, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = FALSE) which is which is equivalent to exp(log(mu)+log(1+1.645*nu*sigma)/nu).Is this right?

Comment: These accounts are duplicates, Robert.  Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge them.

Answer (score 1):

mu=0.8

nu=1.1

sigma=0.4

qBCCGo(0.05, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, nu = nu, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)

gives an exact result.

However
exp(log(mu)+log(1-1.645*nu*sigma)/nu)

is an approximation.

The approximation should be quite accurate if
sigma*abs(nu) < 0.27

[See page 441 of Rigby et al. (2019)]

For example:

mu=0.8

nu=1.1

sigma=0.2

qBCCGo(0.05, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, nu = nu, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)

0.5317892

exp(log(mu)+log(1-1.645*nu*sigma)/nu)

0.5317606

Unfortunately in your example

sigma*abs(nu) = 0.4 * 1.1 = 0.44

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I need to calculate the LLN for each ID after applying the LMS method. For several Ids the value of sigma*abs(nu)  is more than 0.27. So when I use qBCCGo function, I can calculate it but the answer would be NA as soon as I run the formula. So, which function should I use? The formula or qBCCGo?